# How can we prevent inhaling or ingesting mites that live on everyone?

Tags: dermatology, demodex

I was distraught to learn today that ["mites are living on everyone"](https://news.ncsu.edu/2014/08/face-mites-2014/): *Demodex folliculorum*, *Demodex brevis*.

1. What can I do, and not do, to prevent them from entering my body?
2. Am I correct that any contact between anyone's skin and your orifices can facilitate these mites to enter your body? So no eating with bare hands, or touching anyone?

Herbert P. Goodheart, MD [1971 (Hahnemann Medical College)](https://www.linkedin.com/in/herbert-p-goodheart-md-0a6a7214/). [*Acne For Dummies* (2006)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471746983).  p. 217.

> Mites: A mite called *Demodex folliculorum*, which lives in hair
>   follicles, is thought by some scientists to be the cause of
>   rosacea. The belief is that the mites clog oil glands, which
>   leads to the inflammation seen in rosacea. These mites reside
>   in almost everyone’s skin and, like *P. acnes*, may just be innocent bystanders.

Comment: These mites have lived on you and everyone else you know since birth. They've lived on every human who ever lived for millions of years, and suddenly you think there's cause for alarm?

Comment: Out of curiosity though, do these mites start living on the unborn child (in the womb). or get on the host after birth?